# React addEventListener issue with useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, dom-events

I was making a custom image viewer with react and I wanted to implement image navigation with a keyboard ArrowLeft and ArrowRight press

Note:  **currentId** is the currently visible image id

```
useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.key === "ArrowRight") {
      setLoaded(false);
      if (currentId + 1 < props.imgs.length) {
        console.log("right");
        setcurrentId(currentId + 1);
      } else if (currentId + 1 === props.imgs.length) {
        setcurrentId(0);
      }
    } 
    
    if (event.key === "ArrowLeft") {
      setLoaded(false);
      if (currentId - 1 >= 0) {
        console.log("left");
        setcurrentId(currentId - 1);
      } else if (currentId - 1 === -1) {
        setcurrentId(props.imgs.length - 1);
      }
    }
  });
}, [currentId]);
```

Now the issue is that  when I press the keyboard right/left arrow key
the `console.log()`'s execute multiple times with random numbers each time, I understand that it might be running for each state update but no idea how to fix it.

Though when I add `[currenId]` to the `useEffect` the image navigation works but still the console looks like this and makes the navigation slow

[image]

and I've also tried it without the `[currentId]` as a second argument. When I do that it logs this

[image]

and on **ArrowRight** press it sets the `currentId` to 1 and log's right only once but when I press again doesn't do anything

and when **ArrowLeft** is pressed it sets the `currentId` to the length of the array props.imgs - 1
**e.g:-** `props.imgs.length - 1` and log's **nothing**

Comment: A new event listener is **added** after every render. Do you want that? You can use `[]` as second param, to add it only once on component mount.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `addEventListener` like that/at all. React has very specific rules about this because it has to manage its own internal DOM state, and using vanilla JS methods tends to screw that up. It would be useful to the component logic.

Comment: Every time `currentId` changes, you're attaching a new `eventListener` without removing the previous one. In the long run, this could cause serious performance issues.

To solve that, remove the `eventListener` in the return function of the `useEffect`. `return () => { document.removeEventListener... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You keep registering the listener over and over again. React's documentation regarding `useHook` mentions how you can [clean up](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup) certain things, which is exactly what you need for event listeners:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const listener = function(event) {
        // ...
    };
    document.addEventListener('keydown', listener);
    return () => {
        // This function gets called when the "effect wears off"
        // which means we need to unregister the listener
        document.removeEventListener('keydown', listener);
    };
}, [currentId]);
```

The `[currentId]` makes React only call the hook whenever `currentId` changes. React also makes sure that whenever the component gets unmounted, or the hook is about to be re-executed for the same component, that the "cleanup function" gets called. The cleanup function is basically whatever function you return within the hook. If you don't return any, no cleanup function will be called.

Comment: omg, thank you so much it all makes sense now. Really appreciate it.